# Does evil-org-mode work well in org-drill?

Tags: org-mode, evil-mode, org-drill

I am a Vim user interested in using [org-drill](https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill) (org-drill is an extension for org-mode).
But before I invest in learning Emacs, I would like to know if evil-org-mode works well in org-drill.

Comment: The worst that could happen is you need to change some evil bindings for org-drill-mode to get the experience you want (you can make evil bindings per major-mode). You can use `(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'org-drill-mode)` to disable evil in org-drill-mode if you don't like how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

org-drill works great in evil-mode.

Source: An active user of org-drill and an evil-mode user(Spacemacs).